# Workflow: Create List Item when an email is received?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, email

I am working on a list in which, when a particular email is sent to me, a workflow will initiate and add the body of said email to a new list item. However, I do not see the option to start my workflow with an incoming email. Any ideas how I may accomplish this?
I am using SharePoint Designer 2013, and Microsoft Flow.